# Has SQL something like WHERE or HAVING ONLY?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
| ID | SOMEKEY | STATUS |
-------------------------
|  1 | A       |      0 |
|  2 | A       |      1 |
|  3 | B       |      1 |
|  4 | B       |      1 |
```

Now I'd like to get the keys that have **only** STATUS 1, using JPA.

```
select o.somekey
from only_test o
where o.status = 1
and (select count(distinct s.status) from only_test s where s.somekey = o.somekey) = 1
group by o.somekey
```

Works also with JPA and gives only B which is what I want, but looks very clumsy to me.

Isn't there something like

```
having only status = 1
```

in SQL that also works with JPA (JPQL)?

Comment: do you mean "using JPQL", "using SQL", or what ?

Comment: well, I was looking for some standard SQL that also works with JPA (can be rewritten as JPQL), while something specific to JPQL would be fine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select o.somekey
from only_test o
group by o.somekey
having max(o.status) = min(o.status) and min(o.status) = 1;
```

So, I guess the answer to your question is "yes", it does have something like `WHERE ONLY`, but it is phrased differently.

Comment: Very nice. Also performs way better on a table with 10,000,00 rows than my clumsy approach.